# Html.Raw() in combination with Razor?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to add a `<span>` to my view when my session variable is not null.
The value of `Session["error"]` has the right value (I checked), but there is no `<span>` coming in my view when it is filled while the code DOES come into the IF statement.

```
@if (Session["error"] != null) { Html.Raw("<span class=\"alert\"> @Session[\"error\"].ToString() <span>"); }
```

Plz tell me what i need to change. I am a student and new to coding.

Comment: `@Html.Raw` instead of `Html.Raw` (note the `@`)

Comment: @Scott Thanks man! such a small detail, but now it works haha, if you put it in an aswer ill mark it as answered! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `@` to write the output of the function to the response stream.  In short; `@Html.Raw()`.

However, this is not how Razor code should be used.  Instead you can embed HTML directly within your `if`, like so:

```
@if (Session["error"] != null)
{
    <span class="alert">@Session["error"]</span>
}
```

Comment: oh really? let me try that :)

Comment: i tried that before, but i made an typo, i see you have that aswel in the last <span> i missed the "/" to close it haha, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Svenmarim Oh, I missed that as well, nice catch!  Updated.